# "The request is invalid because the app secret is the same as the client token" error when trying to get an access token

Tags: facebook-php-sdk, facebook-oauth, facebook-authentication, facebook-access-token, app-secret

I was using facebook php sdk without any problem to provide facebook login on my website.
Since a few days, I'm unable to log in anymore.
I follow the steps described on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login/ but at step 6 it fails with the following response :

```
{
  error: {
    message: "The request is invalid because the app secret is the same as the client token",
    type: "OAuthException",
    code: 1
  }
}
```

I don't understand why it stopped working. Have you ever had the same problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just encountered this problem and I fixed it by resetting my client token (Advanced > Security on the Facebook App settings page) and changing my app type from Native / Desktop to Web app.

Comment: The problem is that the token is also used on an iPhone app, so resetting the token would break the iPhone app :(

Answer (score 1):

Change the app type from native to web app (Advanced -> App Authentication). Current solution says to reset the client token which was not necessary for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me, neither of the solutions above worked. However, simply by resetting my secret it started working.